# Wordpress Category Filter

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, categories, display

I have a Wordpress website, which you can view here: [PRAXIS3.com](http://www.praxis3.com/p3/work/automotive/).

On this specific page "Automotive" I have a category filter. When I first load the page, the default "**All**" category is selected but if you click on "**All**" a second or third time, it shows EVERY portfolio item that is on the site. Below is the first few lines of the category selector code.

Category Selector Code:

```
<div class="btCatFilter">
    <span class="btCatFilterTitle">Category filter:</span>
    <span class="btCatFilterItem all" data-slug="">All</span>
    <span class="btCatFilterItem" data-slug="acura">Acura</span>
    <span class="btCatFilterItem" data-slug="alfa-romeo">Alfa Romeo</span>
</div>
```

I have some custom CSS set up (to hide certain categories from showing up) on the page which you can view below.

```
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="architecture"] {display: none;}
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="automotive"] {display: none;}
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="branding"] {display: none;}
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="civic"] {display: none;}
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="conceptual"] {display: none;}
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="hospitality"] {display: none;}
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="education"] {display: none;} 
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="environmental-graphics"] {display: none;} 
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="interior-design"] {display: none;} 
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="mixed-use-residential"] {display: none;} 
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="office"] {display: none;} 
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="signage-wayfinding"] {display: none;} 
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="financial"] {display: none;} 
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="retail"] {display: none;} 
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="rollout"] {display: none;} 
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="sustainable"] {display: none;} 
.automotive .btCatFilterItem[data-slug*="workplace"] {display: none;}
```

I'm trying to make it where when you click "**All**" that it shows every project within the "Automotive" category.

I've tried every iteration of the following that I can think of and nothing does the trick.

```
.automotive .btCatFilterItem.all {display: "automotive";}
.automotive .btCatFilterItem.all {display: automotive;}
.automotive .btCatFilterItem.all {display: data-slug*="automotive";}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I think this is actually a database issue rather than CSS or even Javascript.

Looking at your site, the category filter actually is destroying all the tiles and reloading the appropriate ones onto the page via Ajax every time a filter is selected. This means that the filter isn't hiding/showing the tiles, it's actually repopulating the content on the page every time.

I would suggest looking into the plugin settings and see if there's something there you can adjust to pull your automotive content..

#### But maybe that's not an option...

Your tiles themselves need unifying classes or attributes to target with CSS or Javascript. They all have the same `class="gridItem bt11 btGridItemLoaded"`.

If you want to try to hack it together, you need to edit the script that generates the tiles and add a unifying class or attribute like "automotive", then you can hide all the other tiles with something like

`.automotive .btGridItemLoaded:not(.automotive) { display:none; }`

#### btw

The values you used aren't valid for the `display` property. The `display` property has fixed set of values such as `block`, `inline-block`, `none`, and `inherit` among others.

Comment: Regarding the tiles, they all have the category "automotive" tied to them. Could i use that in anyway?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to look at the settings for your gallery plugin. If they're all categorized correctly, you should be able to filter them to show all "automotive" just like you did the car categories.

Comment: Awesome - I'll keep digging around in there.